# Create Multiple Related Lists

Tags: related-list

I am looking for a way to create multiple related lists for Opportunity Products (on Opportunity object) and again for Order Line Items (on Order object).
Aren't there any free apps that can accomplish this?

This is not too complex to answer, really guys?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the kind of question that will get a helpful answer here. This community excels at answering specific, technical questions. It is certainly possible to create what you're looking for from scratch - and it may not require writing code, depending on your requirements. I will attempt an answer based on the limited details you've provided.

Comment: In response to your edit.. yes, your question IS too vague to answer completely without taking pages and covering basic stuff already offered in SF tutorials.. and even then, I did offer an answer that you seem to have ignored. You seem to be looking for someone to do the work for you, without you having to learn anything yourself. This is not the site for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer on how to build this yourself, no code needed. Can't help you with apps, sorry.

**Generally, if you want to create multiple related lists on 'parent' object, you just need to create additional lookups to that parent object on the child object.** (by 'parent' I don't necessarily mean an official parent/child relationship, just the 'one' side of a one-to-many relationship, like an opp's relationship with products)

Currently, your Opp page has only one products related list, because your Opportunity Product object has only one Opportunity lookup field.

To create a second related list for products on your opp page, you just need to create a 2nd Opportunity lookup field on the Opp Product object.

Then, when you add a new Product to your Opportunity (aka when you create an Opportunity Product record), you will see not only the standard 'Opportunity' field, but also your new custom field. Which field you populate determines which related list the product shows up in on the Opp page (it will show up on both if you populate both).